# Lambda exercise

Tags: lambda, predicate

I'm doing some Java OCA test simulations. I don't understand the answer for this exercise:

```
interface Climb {
   boolean isTooHigh(int height, int limit);
}

public class Lambdas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check((h,l) -> l, 5);
    }

    private static void check(Climb climb, int height) {
        if (climb.isTooHigh(height, 10))
            System.out.println("Too");
        else
            System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

I don't understand if `l` is "l" or "1" because the spelling is a little incomprehensible. I also did not understand the logic of this exercise.

Can you tell me what is necessary to correct form: l or 1?
Can you explain me this exercise?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

`(h,l) -> l` is a lambda that takes `h` and `l` and returns `l`. According to `interface Climb`, `h` and `l` as arguments are `int` and the returned `l` should be `bool`; there seems to be an implicit type conversion.

Hence the line `check((h,l) -> l, 5);` is fine and take arguments of the right type `(Climb , int)`.

`(h,l) -> l` is just doing: "let's forget about h, and `if l != 0, return true else if l == 0 return false`".

PS: if it was `1`, the answer would be constantly `true`

### Corrected version

```
interface Climb {
    boolean isTooHigh(int height, int limit);
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check((h,l) -> h>l, 5);
    }
    private static void check(Climb climb, int height) {
            System.out.println(climb.isTooHigh(height, 10) ? "Too":"ok" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to write on my IDE this code with 1 and with l, but in the both cases, there is a compile error:
- with 1, the compile error is "Create local variable 'h';
- with l, the compile error (visible only to the second l) is "Rename in file". I tried to recall the variable l, in limit, but the compile error persists.


Why?

Comment: I don't know which IDE you're using, but you should anyway replace your lambda by `(h,l) -> l == 0`. I used Intellij IDEA, and it worked perfectly, except it was necessar to return a bool, not just `l` (java is strongly typed unlike c/c++).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, on SO, if you got the answer you wanted, you need to "accept", not just +1, and if you got another question, you need to ask another question. Sometimes, there's an investigation, and that's fine to have this in the comments.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. The code of my exercise doesn't, for a compiler error. But the solution for the exercise it isn't "compiler error", but "ok".  I use Eclipse IDE and the code of my exercise doesn't compile. With your IDE, does my code work?

Comment: Now I did another question. Thanks a lot

Comment: No, actually my code is different, at the lambda function. I think the problem should be there even though your error message is cryptic IMO. As I said, your lambda needs to return a `boolean` not an `int`. And in the end, the right lambda should be `(h,l) -> h>l`.